# Category Taxonomy vs default Category post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a trivial question about Taxonomy, and it's confusing me a lot. I've read dozen of posts, blogs I don't want to install a plugin to manage CTP's url cuz I would like to understand this before.

After creating a CPT, if I register categories on this CPT, does WP manage those categories as a "category" or like a taxonomy called "category" ?

-> Do you use "taxonomy-cpt_name.php" or "archives_cpt_name-tax_name.php" (or "category-cpt_name-tax_name") ?

Mine actually use `category.php` for now.

Answer (score 1):

### What's a custom taxonomy

> A taxonomy within WordPress is a way of grouping posts together based on a select number of relationships. By default, a standard post will have two taxonomy types called Categories and Tags which are a handy way of ensuring related content on your website is easy for visitors to find. These two types of taxonomies are included in WordPress by default, but just like any other taxonomy, can be removed or changed and you can even add more if you like.

- *Source @ https://wordpress.org/support/article/taxonomies/*

A custom taxonomy is just a classification tool you can add to a post/page... It can either be **acting as** a `tag`, with no hierarchical order (eg: terms childrens) or as a `category`, with in this case a hierarchical order [using the `hierarchical` argument upon registration](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/).

```
<?php // ...
'hierarchical' => false, // ... registered as tag
'hierarchical' => true, // ... registered as category
// ...
?>
```

> `hierarchical` (boolean) (optional) Is this taxonomy hierarchical (have descendants) like categories or not hierarchical like tags. Default: false.

---

### Reserved Terms

You wouldn't be able to use `category` has the handle, has some terms are reserved for Wordpress itself.

> Avoiding the following reserved terms is particularly important if you are passing the term through the $_GET or $_POST array. Doing so can cause WordPress to respond with a 404 error without any other hint or explanation.

- `attachment`, `attachment_id`
- `author`, `author_name`
- `cat`, `category`, `category__and`, `category__in`, `category__not_in`, `category_name`, `link_category`,
- `taxonomy`, `term`, `terms`
- `tag`, `tag__and`, `tag__in`, `tag__not_in`, `tag_id`, `tag_slug__and`, `tag_slug__in`
- `comments_per_page`, `comments_popup`, `withcomments`, `withoutcomments`
- `custom`, `customize_messenger_channel`, `customized`
- `nav_menu`, `name`, `fields`, `embed`, `title`, `sentence`
- `calendar`, `day`, `hour`, `m`, `minute`, `monthnum`, `year`, `second`
- `perm`, `order`, `orderby`, `offset`, `preview`, `s`, `search`, `debug`, `more`, `nopaging`
- `p`, `page`, `page_id`, `paged`, `pagename`, `cpage`
- `post`, `post__in`, `post__not_in`, `post_format`, `post_mime_type`, `post_status`, `post_tag`, `post_type`, `posts`, `posts_per_archive_page`, `posts_per_page`, `subpost`, `subpost_id`, `showposts`
- `robots`, `error`, `exact`, `feed`, `nonce`, `pb`, `status`, `static`, `theme`, `type`, `types`, `tb`, `w`

Up-to-date list @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/#reserved-terms

---

### Naming your custom taxonomy

Your custom taxonomy can be anything really, beside what's on the reserved terms list. If you really want your custom taxonomy to be called "category" I would suggest you use synonyms (`set`, `listing`, ...) or underscores (`cpt_category`, ...)

---

### Sharing your custom taxonomy

Default taxonomies (`category`, `tags`...) or custom taxonomies can be shared. You could use for example the default taxonomies `category` and `tags` in your custom post type.

While using `register_post_type` you can specify which taxonomies to use using the `taxonomies` argument.

```
<?php / ...
'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'tag', ),
/ ...
?>
```

Comment: If you share the taxonomies category between post and cpt it will work in both yes

Comment: Yes I understand category and tags are "higher" than post and CPT.

They both are like "global" of the site

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for replying,

One great thing : I understand you can't use 'category' for a Tax. name, I couldn't find the affirmation or not somewhere.

Means 'category' works in CPT as in posts (width category.php) ? ok.
But it seems on WP hierarchy, I can't use a "category-{cpt_name}.php" in order to filter the custom posts in category template (to have a category with just the posts of the CPT).

So I will probably create a hierarchical taxonomy called "cptName_category" in order to use a "taxonomy-{name}.php" template.
Subsidiary question 1 : why category-{cpt_name}.php has not be integreted in wp ?
->for sure, the reason is logic :) (as we can see on hierarchy).

++Thank you a lot,
Nicolas.